# How to access the mockmodule in a jest test

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs, enzyme

I don't understand how I can access the instance of a mocked module I use in a test. Below you can find the code of my test where I mock the "highcharts" library and an extension to highcharts called "funnel". Funnel is simply a function which you call on Highcharts e.g. funnel(Highcharts) which extends Highcharts. I'm mocking this functionality because I have the problem that I need to test that I didn't call the function multiple times on Highcharts because that causes unexpected behavior and some times Highcharts to crash. Here is the code of my test:

```
import React, {PureComponent} from 'react';
import {mount} from 'enzyme';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/js/highcharts';

// mocking the highcharts modules
jest.mock('highcharts/js/highcharts', () => ({
  Chart: jest.fn(),
  setOptions: jest.fn(),
  seriesTypes: {},
}));

// mocking an extension
jest.mock('highcharts/js/modules/funnel.src.js', function() {
  return function mockHighcharts(mockHighcharts) {
    const localMock = {...{}, ...mockHighcharts};
    localMock.seriesTypes.funnel = jest.fn();
    return localMock;
  };
});

describe('Chart', () => {
  class Tester extends PureComponent {
    render() {
      return null;
    }
  }

  // Each Chart needs at least one child hence the Tester component
  it.only('should render', () => {
    const component = mount(
      <Chart type="funnel">
        <Tester />
      </Chart>,
      Highcharts
    );
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

I don't understand how can I access the mocked Highcharts module to see if my mock function got called on the mocked import. When I debug and check the status of it in the Chart component (the component I test here), I can see that the test uses my mock modules and calls my mock function on it. But my problem is that I only have that state when I mount the component but I can't access that state of my import in my test and thus not assert my test behavior.

Below you can find a simplified version of my Chart. I have the functionality that I dynamically load certain extension when needed (in this simplified version I just always load funnel unless it is already loaded).

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/js/highcharts';

export default class Chart extends Component {
  state = {
    chart: {
      // my chart options
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (!Highcharts.seriesTypes.funnel) {
      import('highcharts/js/modules/funnel.src.js').then((funnel) => funnel(Highcharts));
    }
    this.instance = Highcharts.Chart('myChart', this.state.chart);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="myChart" />
    );
  }
}
```

What I liked to do is something like

```
expect(Highcharts).toMatchSnapshot();
```

But the Highcharts instance in my test is not the same as in my component when I mount it. I there even a way to access it or is my architecture somewhere wrong?

Thanks for you inputs :)

Answer (score 1):

If you mock a module like this

```
jest.mock('./myMockedModule', ()=>jest.fn())
```

you can access them by importing the module like this:

```
import MockedModule from './myMockedModule'
const mockedFunction = jest.fn()
const Mock = {mockedFunction}
MockedModule.mockImplementation(Mock)
Mock.mockedFunction()
expect(mockedFunction).toHaveBeenCalledOnce()
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure if we talk about the same thing. My problem is not that I can't access the mocked function. That totally works and I'm able to use my mocked function. But I would like to observe the change my mocked function has done to the module I called the function on. When I call ```funnel(Highcharts)``` I add a property to the Highcharts import. So my problem is I don't have access to that Highcharts instance where I called the function on, not to call the function.

Comment: Also update my query to what I think you are looking add. Now you have the instance of the object mock will return right in your test.